# Composition over Inheritance

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

i saw an example of ActionListener use in code by implementing ActionListener.
but here i wanna use functionality of ActionListener by using Ref.Var. of ActionListener.

```
JButton createButton(){
    ActionListener al;       
    JButton button = new JButton();

    button.setBounds(130, 100, 100, 40); 
    button.setText("aaa");
    button.setSize(100, 40);
    button.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(button);

    return button;       
}
```

look at ActionListener reference here . how to use this ref.var on button to listen event on button

Comment: ow ... key, besides the fact that your code is incomplete, what is your question? You'll still need a class that implements ActionListener, though.

Comment: look at ActionListener reference here . how to use this ref.var on button to listen event on button.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking about how to add an action listener to the button? If so, did you have a look at the Javadocs or any decent Swing tutorial?

Comment: how to listen button event by using ActionListener type variable ?

Comment: @infocatalyst you'll still have to implement it.

Comment: Btw, `button.setLayout(null);` doesn't make much sense since the button normally doesn't have children. Also setting the size and bounds of the button isn't good style. Use the parent component's (aka container's) layout manager instead.

Comment: Did you look at any documentation at all? Hint: provide an action via `JButton(Action)` or add an action listener via `addActionListener(...)`.

Comment: how to implement ActionListener on button.?

Comment: @infocatalyst you've been given the answer(s) already. Have you tried to follow them?

Comment: pls answer me by showing me code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JButton createButton(){
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // run code;
      }
    };       
    JButton button = new JButton();

    button.setBounds(130, 100, 100, 40); 
    button.setText("aaa");
    button.setSize(100, 40);
    button.addActionListener(al);
    frame.add(button);

    return button;       
}
```

OR

```
jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    //run code;
  } 
} );
```

It's basically exactly the same as having the containing class implement ActionListener: you provide an implementation, and you configure your button to listen to it.

Comment: is there any way that i compose my createButton() method by declaring ref. variables or instances of ActionListener , ActionEvent in the createButton() method and directly call actionPerformed method without override (imperative style totally / no methods in the createButton() method )

Comment: what i understand: "jbutton invoked addActionListener method in which we pass new Instance of ActionListener which has a abstract method actionPerformed that we must to override" ....              now what i mean to say: can we use ActionListener here without making new instance,  but by making ref. var like ActionListener al = "Assign any existing type here " .  etc then further assignments until button event listened by anywhere we want. means everything in imperative style statements ... not by overriding methods.

Comment: what do you mean by "Assign any existing type here"? If you declare it to be an ActionListener, it has to be an ActionListener, you can't assign a String or ArrayList to it. Also: what do you mean by: "everything in imperative style statements" ?

Comment: means that before declaring ActionListener var. definitely we have something that will assigned to ActionListener or we need to assign ActionListener to Something exist already to work further...   imperative : declaring var(s), Assign values or ref. to Var(s) , invoke api methods directly to ref. var(s)... basically i want to write code like unstructured programming style / do goto style / make order to types directly to do something without using unnecessary oop ...

Comment: ... unnecessary oop? Writing the code you want to run is not 'unneccessary'. You need an implemented instance of ActionListener to add to your JButton, as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: how actionPerformed method called? what is ActionEvent parameter, and where it comes from?

Comment: that you shouldn't worry about. one a JButton is pressed, an ActionEvent is triggered (Java does this, you don't have to code this yourself). The Listener detects this, and automatically the actionPerformed is called

Comment: code like this: JButton button=new JButton(); ActionListener l = ; ActionEvent ae = ; l.actionPerformed(ae); button.addActionListener(l); ... what can we assign to ActionListener and ActionEvent to complete code functionality...

Comment: @infocatalyst that code makes zero sense. again. truly.